# Who can we write a will for on Hol Hamoed

Tags: chol-hamoed, legal-documents, masechet-moed-katan

The Mishnah in [Moed Katan 3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Moed_Katan.3.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> וְאֵלּוּ כּוֹתְבִין בַּמּוֹעֵד ... דְּיָתֵיקֵי
>
> They may write the following documents during the festival: ... wills [of a dying person]

The parenthetical addition of "of a dying person" is added in multiple translations so I assume it comes from somewhere.

Who are we able to write a will for? Anyone? Anyone who is dying? Anyone who is likely to die on Hol Hamoed?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%94

Answer (score 2):

[Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Moed_Katan.3.3.4?lang=bi):

> דייתיקי. מתנת שכיב מרע. ופירוש דייתיקי, דא תהא למיקם ולהיות, שדברי שכיב מרע ככתובין וכמסורין דמו.‏
>
> A *deyathiki*: A gift given by a dying person. The meaning of *deyathiki*: 'This is to be established and to endure', as the words of a dying person are as if they have been written and transferred.

It seems that the *mishnah* is granting permission to write down the instructions of someone on their deathbed.